# Scraping the top ten stories of a website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the website: http://edition.cnn.com/EVENTS/1996/year.in.review/
and trying to acquire the top 10 stories, this is my attempt so far, and im wondering if there is an easier way that i'm overlooking to get this in one go? Also, I'm trying to find a way to remove the linebreaks between each print, since i don't know why there is a gap between each headline.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = """
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Top Ten Stories From 1996</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" LINK="#162323" ALINK="#FFFFCE" VLINK="#162323">

<CENTER>
<P><BR>

<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
    <TR>
        <TD><IMG SRC="logos.gif" WIDTH="112" HEIGHT="60" ALIGN="TOP"></TD>
        <TD><IMG SRC="banner.gif" WIDTH="360" HEIGHT="60" ALIGN="TOP"></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</P>
</CENTER>


<BLOCKQUOTE>
    <CENTER>

    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="2">
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="90" VALIGN="TOP" ROWSPAN="11">
            <P ALIGN="RIGHT"><B><TT>What were the biggest stories of the year?</TT></B><BR>
            <BR>
            <FONT SIZE="2">It's a question journalists like to ask themselves at the end of every
            year. Now you can join in the process. Here are our selections for the top ten news
            stories of 1996.<BR>
            <BR>
            Disagree with our choices? Then tell us what stories you think were most compelling
            in the poll below.</FONT>
        </TD>
        <TD WIDTH="4" ROWSPAN="11"></TD>
        <TD VALIGN="MIDDLE" ROWSPAN="11"><IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="250" ALIGN="MIDDLE"></TD>
        <TD WIDTH="10" ROWSPAN="11"></TD>
        <TD COLSPAN="4" VALIGN=TOP>
            <P ALIGN="CENTER"><IMG SRC="generic/topten.gif" WIDTH="263" HEIGHT="24" ALIGN="MIDDLE" VSPACE="5">
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/israel/israel.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/1.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/israel/israel.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>Israel</B> elects <B>Netanyahu</A></B></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/twa/twa.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/2.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/twa/twa.index.html" TARGET=_top>Crash of TWA Flight 800</A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/yeltsin/yeltsin.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/3.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/yeltsin/yeltsin.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>Russia</B> elects <B>Yeltsin</B></A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/clinton/clinton.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/4.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/clinton/clinton.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>U.S</B>. elects <B>Clinton</B></A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/hutu/hutu.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/5.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/hutu/hutu.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>Hutu-Tutsi</B> conflict in central Africa</A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/bosnia/bosnia.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/6.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/bosnia/bosnia.index.html" TARGET=_top>Peace, elections in <B>Bosnia</B></A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/saudi/saudi.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/7.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/saudi/saudi.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>U.S</B>. base bombed in <B>Saudi Arabia</B></A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/olympics/olympics.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/8.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/olympics/olympics.index.html" TARGET=_top>Centennial <B>Olympic</B> Games</A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/aids/aids.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/9.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/aids/aids.index.html" TARGET=_top>Advances against <B>AIDS</B></A></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/unabomb/unabomb.index.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="generic/10.gif" WIDTH="17" HEIGHT="17" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER=0></A></TD>
        <TD><A HREF="topten/unabomb/unabomb.index.html" TARGET=_top><B>Unabomb</B> suspect <B>Ted Kaczynski</B> arrested</A></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>
<BR clear = "all">


    <TABLE WIDTH=300>
    <TR>
    <TD>
    <CENTER><A HREF="topten/poll.html" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="poll.gif" WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="60" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER="0"></CENTER></A>
    </TD>
    <TD>
    <CENTER><A HREF="http://www-cgi.cnn.com/cgi-bin/quiz/yir_main/go.pl/main" TARGET=_top><IMG SRC="quiz.gif" WIDTH="120" HEIGHT="60" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER="0"></CENTER></A>
    </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD COLSPAN=2><CENTER><A TARGET=_top HREF="http://www-cgi.cnn.com/cgi-bin/poll/heavypoll.pl?slug=9612%2Fyir_top_10">The top 10 stories according to our users</A></CENTER></TD></TR>
    </TABLE>


    <IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE"><BR>

    <BR><IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE"><BR>
    <BR>

    <CENTER>
    <A HREF="http://pathfinder.com/time/bestof1996/index.html" TARGET=_top>
    T I M E: The Best of 1996</A>
    <BR clear = "all"><BR>
        <A HREF="http://pathfinder.com/@@qsdFOQcA62PJWEWu/time/moy/index.html" TARGET=_top>
    T I M E: Man of the Year</A>
    <BR clear = "all"><BR>
    <A HREF="http://pathfinder.com/time/1996/" TARGET=_top>
    <IMG SRC="time.gif" WIDTH="540" HEIGHT="50" ALIGN="MIDDLE" BORDER="0"></A>
    <BR clear = "all"><BR><BR>
    <IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE">
    </CENTER>
    <BR clear = "all">

    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="63%">
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="100%">
            <P><B><TT>What makes a </TT></B><FONT SIZE="5"><TT><B>big</B></TT></FONT><TT><B>
            story </B></TT><FONT SIZE="5"><TT><B>BIG?</B></TT></FONT>


            <BLOCKQUOTE>
            <P>It depends on your criteria, of course, and your perspective. That's why we offered
            a poll to find out what you think.</P>
            <P>For our list, we polled producers throughout the CNN/Pathfinder family of networks
            and publications, and weighed such criteria as a story's long-term implications,
            geopolitical significance, user interest, amount of coverage, and old-fashioned newsworthiness.
            All these things help make a &quot;big&quot; story big.</P>

            <P>By no means do we think our lists are the final word. Even our polls among CNN
            producers turned up a wide variety of responses. The process is meant to encourage
            you to reconsider the stories that dominated the media during the past year and determine
            for yourself which were mere sensations and which were truly significant.
            </BLOCKQUOTE>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE>

<BR CLEAR=ALL>
<BR>
<CENTER>
<BR CLEAR=ALL>
<BR>
<IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE">
<BR CLEAR=ALL><BR>

<TABLE WIDTH=300><TR VALIGN=CENTER>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER><IMG SRC="what_you_think.gif" ALT="What you think" WIDTH="60" HEIGHT="59" BORDER="0"></TD>
<TD><STRONG><A NAME="_top" HREF="/feedback/index.html">Tell us what you think</A></STRONG><BR><BR>
<STRONG><A NAME="_top" HREF="/feedback/comments.html">You said it...</A></STRONG></TD>
</TR></TABLE>

<BR CLEAR=ALL>
<BR>
<IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE">
<BR CLEAR=ALL><BR>
</CENTER>

<CENTER><A HREF="generic/credits.index.html" TARGET=_top><TT><B>C R E D I T S</B></TT></A></CENTER>

<BR CLEAR=ALL>
<BR>
<IMG SRC="generic/dot.gif" WIDTH="450" HEIGHT="1" ALIGN="MIDDLE">
<BR CLEAR=ALL><BR>
<CENTER><A HREF="#TOP"><TT><B>Back to top</B></TT></A></CENTER>
<BR CLEAR=ALL><BR>
<FONT SIZE=-1><P>&#169; 1996 Cable News Network, Inc.<BR>
All Rights Reserved.</FONT>
<H6><A HREF="http://cnn.com/interactive_legal.html" target=_top>Terms</A> under which this
     service is provided to you.</H6>
</CENTER>
</CENTER>
    </BLOCKQUOTE>


</BODY>

</HTML>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
td_list = soup.find_all('td')
count = 0
for link in td_list:
    if count == 20:
        pass
    elif link.a is not None:
        print(link.text.strip())
        count += 1
```

Output:

```
Israel elects Netanyahu

Crash of TWA Flight 800

Russia elects Yeltsin

U.S. elects Clinton

Hutu-Tutsi conflict in central Africa

Peace, elections in Bosnia

U.S. base bombed in Saudi Arabia

Centennial Olympic Games

Advances against AIDS

Unabomb suspect Ted Kaczynski arrested
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've used `re` to shorten the road to select all tag `a` where `href` value starts with `topten`, also you can do it with different way such as.

```py
for item in soup.select("a[href^=topten]"):
```

And then i got all text within the tag, then `stripped` it with `strip=True` and putted an empty `separator` so the `text` will not be assigned within together.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile("^topten")):
        item = item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        if item:
            print(item)


main("http://edition.cnn.com/EVENTS/1996/year.in.review/main.html")
```

Output:

```
Israel elects Netanyahu
Crash of TWA Flight 800
Russia elects Yeltsin
U.S . elects Clinton
Hutu-Tutsi conflict in central Africa
Peace, elections in Bosnia
U.S . base bombed in Saudi Arabia
Centennial Olympic Games
Advances against AIDS
Unabomb suspect Ted Kaczynski arrested
```

Comment: can you tell me why'd you use a re expression and the item.get_text

Comment: what does strip do, and how does seperator work there

Comment: @MahdeenSky I've updated my answer, you can avoid using `regex` as well